# Multifile rename Bash script issue

Tags: bash, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, mv

I was using a code to rename files and a very interesting problem emerged: It worked in a computer running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5, but it failed on Mac OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard.

The code is:

```
for i in *; do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/..//'`; done
```

and the error I got is:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

It's very weird because mv is working normally if not in a `for` loop...

Anyone know what should I do to get it working?

Comment: try giving some qualifier instead of *

Comment: `for i in *`? You are traversal the current directory. I guess you want to traversal the last directory. Use "../*"?

Comment: It works for me (assuming the intent is to remove the first two characters of each filename). Do you have any files with only two characters in the name? Files with spaces in the name?

Comment: @GordonDavisson The intent is right. Maybe the problem is all files have space in the name, and actually that's why I want to rename every  file in this folder. Also more than two character in every filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have files with spaces (or certain other shell metachaarcters) it's critical that you put all variable references in double-quotes. Otherwise, if you have e.g. `i="File Name.txt"`, you'll be running a command like `mv File Name.txt le Name.txt` and it'll think you're specifying 4 filenames not just 2. The other standard mistake (which you're *not* making) is using `for file in $(ls)`, which gets confused by spaces before the names even make it into the variable.

Also, I'm a bit concerned about short filenames and name conflicts. Even if you think you don't have any short filenames, if you have the dotglob shell option set you'll wind up trying to rename the pseudo-files "." and "..", which won't go well at all. Also, if you have e.g. files named "abcdefg" and "cdefg", the script will rename the first over the second (silently erasing the second), then rename *that* to "efg".

So, here's my proposed rewrite (also using @TrueY's suggestion for shortening the filename):

```
for i in *; do
    if [ ${#i} -le 2 ]; then
        echo "$i: not renamed (too short)" >&2
    elif [ -e "${i:2}" ]; then
        echo "$i: not renamed (${i:2} already exists)" >&2
    else
        mv "$i" "${i:2}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `bash` string substitution:

```
for i in *; do mv $i ${i/??/}; done
```

or

```
for i in *; do mv $i ${i#??}; done
```

Comment: +1! Or a shorter version: `mv $i ${i:2}` :) But it still fails if there is a file with two char filename.

Comment: All filenames have more than two char. I tried the three solutions above and none worked... Could the problem be that there are spaces in the filenames?

Comment: `for i in *` should not break on spaces. Can you please post the error you are getting by running this command?